# BreezeJS Not returning from FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I don't know what happpened here,but all of the sudden breeze is not returning results from local cache using fetchStrategy..

This is not making any sense to me ? Possible some kind of bug ?

Obviously the entities are in the cache after the first query .. 
Tested in console

`$scope.em.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from('Company').using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromServer)).then(function() {console.log('returned'); })
Object {}
VM35268:2 returned
$scope.em.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from('Company').using(breeze.FetchStrategy.FromLocalCache)).then(function() {console.log('returned'); })
Object {}`

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a major metadata inconsistency. The Typemap key was Companies and not Company .. for whatever reason...